# In finite field $\mathbb F, \max( \deg(f), \deg(g) ) \geq |\mathbb F|$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to show that in a finite field $\mathbb F$, where $f,g \in \mathbb F[x]$ if $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb F$ and $f\neq g$ then $\max( \deg(f), \deg(g) ) \geq |\mathbb F|$.

Where $|\mathbb F|$ is the number of elements in the finite field.

Comment: Please include your thoughts and efforts in 
this and future posts. Formatting tips 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_1,\dots, a_n$ be the elements of $|\mathbb F|$.

If $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb F$, then 
$f(x)-g(x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb F$,
and so
$h(x)=(x-a_1)\cdots(x-a_n)$ divides $f(x)-g(x)$.
Therefore, we must have
$n= \deg(h) \le \deg(f-g) \le \max(\deg(f),\deg(g)) $.

Comment: Thank you for the answer so much, but as I haven't yet studied groups, I regret that I don't understand it. However, as soon as I do groups, I will read this. Thank you :)

Comment: @AhmedAlaa It is very strange to me that you are doing polynomials over finite fields without having done group theory.

Comment: @AhmedAlaa, I've removed the group stuff, which wasn't needed.

Comment: @Cameron I am using A First Course in Abstract Algebra by Marlow Anderson which does rings and fields before groups, I guess that's not very common in abstract algebra courses though.